# I am trying to Bind Multiple IPEndPoints to a List of Sockets

Tags: c#, linq, sockets

I am trying to Bind multiple IPEndPoints to Multiple Sockets in a list, The problem is the binding of them all, Let me give you an example I have a hundred Sockets so I am generating hundred IPEndPoints and I am trying to loop through them all and Bind the IPEndPoints that look like this in an example of explanations
Socket 1 Binds 192.168.1.67:1
Socket 2 Binds 192.168.1.67.2
so on and so on

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tcprange; i++)
     {
         int[] arraysockets; 
         //Regular TCP/IP 
Socket TCPIPSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
TCPIPSocketList.Add(TCPIPSocket);

 foreach (Socket ClientSocket in TCPIPSocketList)
 {
   ClientSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ExclusiveAddressUse, false); //This is a Property setting for the socket allows it to have multiple bindings
  ClientSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true); //This allows for the socket to have reuse the same local ip 

  // The socket will linger for 10 seconds after  
   ClientSocket.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 10);

   // Disable the Nagle Algorithm for this tcp socket.
      ClientSocket.NoDelay = true;
    //IPEndPoint[] ip = new IPEndPoint[tcprange];
      arraysockets = new int[tcprange];
      arraysockets[i] = i;
   //Server Endpoint for Receiving incoming data from clients
   // ip[i].Address = IPAddress.Any;
   // ip[i].Port = arraysockets[i];
    IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, arraysockets[i]); <--// This works when I Use a single integer I need an array of socket numbers with the same ip that's why have the reuse settings on my socket
    lstIncom.Items.Add("--Client Log--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
   lstIncom.Items.Add("Socket# " + ip.ToString().Substring(7, 3));
    ClientSocket.Bind(ip);
    ClientSocket.Listen(10);
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: the problem is I can not bind the ip IPEndPoint with all socket number endpoints in that array it doesn't work? I can only use a single static value, when I try to use the arraysocket[I] as the socket numbers for the multiple sockets it doesn't work.

Comment: the code could be right im not sure if my router or something on physical network is allowing a hundred sockets and socket numbers 0-99 to work. so I know it runs listens but my client isn't able to select and number from 0-99 when pointing to the server and find the tcp service portal so its one or the other